# Inserting different arrays in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have inserted an array in the ArrayList but after inserting the second one the first one becomes the same as the second one.

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] parent = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        parent[0] = rand(4,1);
        parent[1] = rand(6, -2);
        parent[2] = rand(2, 1);
        parent[3] = rand(-1, -2);

        list.add(parent);
    }

    // to print the arrays of the parent
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int[] arr ;
        arr = list.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Value "+arr[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("Next Array");
    }
```

Rand function // it is a random function generating random values in a range

```
public static int rand(int max,int min)
{
  Random rand = new Random();
  int value = 0;
  return value = rand.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min; 
}
```

I have ran it many times but the values of both the arrays are same.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IjRw.png)

I could not understand it why get the same values of both arrays.

Comment: move the definition of `parent` into the `for` loop.

Comment: Because an `int[]` is an object, and not a primitive value. You are storing the same array twice in the list.

Comment: That is because the object the added in the list the first time is the same that the one added the second time. Therefore it is modified during the second iteration of the for loop and printed twice.

Comment: @Thomas Prepare to get attacked for saying *pass-by-reference*. Attacks coming in 3...2...1...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    int[] parent = new int[4];
    parent[0] = rand(4,1);
    parent[1] = rand(6, -2);
    parent[2] = rand(2, 1);
    parent[3] = rand(-1, -2);

    list.add(parent);
}
```

Otherwise you are creating an array, settings its value, adding it to the list. Then you are changing the values of the *same* array and adding it a second time again. Therefore **the list contains the same array twice**. The array itself contains the random numbers of the second iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the array `parent` into the ArrayList, then changing the values of `parent`, and then adding it again into the ArrayList. The ArrayList holds the int[] by *reference*, so when you change the values in `parent`, you are changing the values in list.get(0)

You need to create a new array each time you add into the ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
int[] parent = new int[4];
```

needs to go **into** your loop.

Otherwise you keep adding the **same** array instance multiple times to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Because you add same object of the `parent` array to your `ArrayList`.

```
int[] parent = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    parent[0] = rand(4,1);
    parent[1] = rand(6, -2);
    parent[2] = rand(2, 1);
    parent[3] = rand(-1, -2);

    list.add(parent); // it's still the same object, but now twice in the arraylist
}
```

In order to fix it you could move it into the for-loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 int[] parent = new int[4];
 .....
}
```

The reason why you see duplicate array values is that it's not duplicate but more like the same array which is available two times in your `ArrayList`.